# Cannot read/write a second drive in MBP 13

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro

I changed my original HDD for a SDD earlier this year and I just got one more SSD for my MBP 13 (2012) that I used to replace DVD drive. I'm using Mountain Lion.

The SSD looks to be recognized allright, but I can't format it.

Then I removed the main drive and tried the new one as the main drive and did the boot using a USB drive with MAC OS and everyhing worked as it should (like I just had one drive). However when I bring the first drive back together with the second they both show up but I can't use it. Seems like I have no permission, but when I look at it's properties it says I can read and write to it.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you didn't mess with flat cable while changed HD to SSD. That seems to be  the same issue I had few months ago.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Do you mean that the cable was damaged, or loosened, or misconfigured, and were you able to resolve it at the time?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem...

http://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/macbookpro_13_unibody_early11_dd_h/

But it is strange... the SSD is recognised as 6G, but doesn't work well...

I'm trying install the SSD OCZ Vertex 4, I'm using OCZ Vertex 3 in the main drive.

Thx